# Sequential characterization of integrability

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-explanation, riemann-integration

I'm having some difficulties trying to understand a step from the following proof, which is about the sequential characterization of integrability. Here's the theorem:

[image]
[image]

And here's the part of the proof I cannot totally understand:

[image]

I understand why squeeze theorem can be applied, and I agree with the fact that it implies:

$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}{[U(f;P_n)-U(f)]} = 0
$$

Yet still I don't see why the above limit can be 'split' into two different limits, since, in general, the fact that:
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}{(a_n-b_n)} = 0
$$
does not imply the existence of the following limits:
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}{a_n}, \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}{b_n}. 
$$

Thanks beforehand!!

Comment: Where is this proof from?

Comment: It’s from the following notes, you can find them here https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/intro_analysis_pdf/intro_analysis.html . I personally think they’re quite nice.

Comment: Do you notice that here $b_n=U(f) $ is constant (independent of $n$) and hence its limit exists and equals the same constant value $U(f) $. Then $a_n=(a_n-b_n) +b_n\to 0+U(f)$.

Comment: +1 for raising a doubt. Don't trust unless you understand it fully.

Answer (score 1):

Since $U(f) = L(f) = \int_a^b f(x) \, dx$, we have

$$L(P_n,f) \leqslant \int_a^bf(x) \, dx \leqslant U(P_n,f),$$

and

$$0 \leqslant U(P_n,f) - \int_a^bf(x) \, dx \leqslant U(P_n,f) - L(P_n,f)\underset{n \to \infty}\longrightarrow 0,$$

which implies  $U(P_n,f) \to \int_a^b f(x) \,dx$ as $n \to \infty$.

We can show in a simlar way that  $L(P_n,f) \to \int_a^b f(x) \,dx$.

Comment: In general $a_n-b_n \to 0$ does not imply existence of limits for $a_n,b_n$ but in this case the limits can be independently shown to exist and are equal.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you should denote $a_n:=L(f;P_n)$, $c:=L(f)$, $d:=U(f)$ and $b_n:=U(f;P_n)$, where

$$ a_n \leq c\leq d\leq b_n. $$

You know that $a_n-b_n\to 0$, which as you said implies that

$$ a_n-d\to0 \quad \text{and} \quad b_n-c\to 0. $$